# Batch command(s) to show all files in folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using this method to save file names in folder into a txt file.

Let's say I have file1.txt and file2.txt in C:\somefolder\somefolder1\ and file3.txt and file4.txt in C:\somefolder\somefolder2\

```
cd C:\somefolder\somefolder1\
dir /b /o *.* >> paths.txt
cd C:\somefolder\somefolder2\
dir /b /o *.* >> paths.txt
```

And I get a result like this.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
paths.txt
```

and

```
file3.txt
file4.txt
paths.txt
```

I need a code that would save files in 1 file with their paths. So like this.

```
C:\somefolder\somefolder1\file1.txt
C:\somefolder\somefolder1\file2.txt
C:\somefolder\somefolder2\file3.txt
C:\somefolder\somefolder2\file4.txt
```

And I need a way to specify where that file would be. Like for example the location of such a file would be. C:\somefolder\paths.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
"C:\somefolder\somefolder1"
"C:\somefolder\somefolder2"
) do dir /b /s /a-d >>"C:\somefolder\paths.txt"
```

Comment: Please delete all your comments from here.  They are unnecessary.

Comment: Works great. Thanks for you help. All the unnecessary stuff deleted.